# Conformality of elliptical annuli

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there any analogous to a theorem due to Riemann for conformal equivalency of two confocal elliptical annuli?Pehaps relating conformality to ratio of minor slash major axes?

( That theorem states that $\Delta= \{ z: 0<r<|z|<R \} $ and  $\Delta'= \{ z: 0<r'<|z|<R' \} $ are conformally equivalent iff $\frac{R}{r}=\frac{R'}{r'}$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hint:

Study the Joukowski map

$$J(z):={1\over2}\left(z+{1\over z}\right)\ .$$

This map transforms concentric circles $\partial D_r$ of radius $r\geq 1$  into confocal ellipses with foci ${\pm1}$.